# convert html to json in PHP

Tags: php, html, json, request

Im trying to do request in php but the answer is in HTML, how can i convert it in json ?

case 'getzipcode':

```
$CITY= @$_POST['city'];

$STREET= @$_POST['street'];

$Q= "https://www.israelpost.co.il/zip_data.nsf/SearchZip?OpenAgent&Location=".$CITY."&Street=".$STREET ;

$results = file_get_contents($Q);

$results= json_encode($results, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

print($results);
```

For the moment i got this :
"\n\n</head>\n<body text="#000000">\nRES84623000\n</body>\n</html>\n"

thank you in advance,

Comment: You don't convert HTML to JSON. HTML is a markup language while JSON is a data format. Two completely different things. If you want to get some data from a HTML page, you need to use something like [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: You could also contact the API provider to see if there's some other endpoint, or flag, you can use to get the result as JSON instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completly agree with Magnus in the comments, that you should contact the API providers, and ask them for an JSON endpoint..

But if that is not possible, you could do something like this :

```
<?php 
$theFile = file_get_contents('https://www.israelpost.co.il/zip_data.nsf/SearchZip?OpenAgent&Location=%25u05EA%25u05DC%20%25u05D0%25u05D1%25u05D9%25u05D1%20-%20%25u05D9%25u05E4%25u05D5&POB=&Street=%25u05D3%25u05D9%25u05D6%25u05E0%25u05D2%25u05D5%25u05E3&House=99&Entrance=');

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //Prevents Warnings, remove if desired
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($theFile);
$body = "";
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    $body .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
}
echo $body;
```

This will get the content of the body tag for you.

This example will output `RES86439611` - whatever that means to you

Comment: @ivass If the answer suffices to your need, please accept it, so that future people with the same problem will have an easier time finding an answer. Glad that it worked out for you. (note, it also gives me points ;)